# Fiddler settings in fiddlercore

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddler, fiddlercore

How do i enable the highlighted Fiddler option in FiddlerCore? `Use PAC Script`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzvrH.png

I've looked through all the docs and have browsed through all available settings presented by `Fiddler.CONFIG` and `FiddlerCoreStartupFlags` but cannot find a way to get FiddlerCore to register as a proxy using its internal pac script rather than a system wide proxy.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this isn't currently exposed in FiddlerCore; `CONFIG.bHookWithPAC` is marked `internal`.

In builds after 4.4.9.8, this will be exposed as `FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.HookUsingPACFile`.